# Do I need any drivers?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, laptop, dell

I am new to Ubuntu so I have some doubts regarding Ubuntu. My system is Dell Inspiron N4010 with 3GB RAM and preloaded with Windows 64 bit. I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So I downloaded the 64 bit version. Will it work perfectly on my machine? Last time I used some old versions of Ubuntu and the WiFi was not working properly. Will there be any issue like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Do I need any drivers?***

YES and NO.  It depends ..

The need for additional (or alternate) **Ubuntu** drivers, particularly for WiFi, is a generally related to two underlying causes.

---

**(1.)** The device or platform is so **new** that the chipset or model is as yet unknown to **Ubuntu**.

This can often be resolved by:

(a.) Waiting a few weeks, for someone else to find and resolve the issue.  They will then post a comment or workaround.  Often this will simply require a 'blacklist' or settings change, so the **new** device is **not** mistaken for a similar (but **not** identical) device.

(b.) ***bleeding edge*** - Going to the (chipset's) manufacturers website, and downloading and  compiling a custom driver.  While this **heroic** approach may suit some people, it will often be defeated by the next update, kernel change, or simple be inferior to option (a.) or (c.).

(c.) Waiting a month (or more), from when the device first reaches the market. By this time any changes or exceptions for this platform will be incorporated into updates that **Ubuntu** will install on first update (after installation). *You will still need to work around wireless issues, i.e. connect first by Ethernet cable, to easily and simply resolve this.*

---

**(2.)** The device or platform is **older**, little known, or not intended (by vendor) to support **Ubuntu**.

This can really only be resolved by:

(a.) Finding and visiting websites dedicated to installing **Ubuntu** on this platform.  Example would include: **HP TouchPad**, (various) gaming platforms, embedded designs (including TV decoders), etc.

(b.) ***bleeding edge*** - Going to the (chipset's) manufacturers website, and downloading and  compiling a custom driver.  And not forgetting that this **heroic** approach will often be defeated by the next update, kernel change, or *something else ..*

---

**SO ..**

***Try to install Ubuntu, and report back (to this forum) on any issues (or success) with your efforts.***

Answer (score 7):

You could try the live CD and check if it works or not? It will not install anything to your harddrive, all you have to do is run it from a disk or USB drive.

[This Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) is a good place to start with if you are unsure about booting from the live CD. The live CD is essentially a full Ubuntu install, except it runs on CD/DVD/USB, doesn't modify your harddrive in anyway (unless instructed to explicitly) and it does not save any changes you make.  This way you can check if everything you need works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Live CD is the preferred way to go, if you need to make sure about everything working properly.
Although it won't let you save any modified settings like changing font size of your terminal, or if you want to manually change some settings for your wifi if its not working by default.
For the above to work there is tool named [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), available for windows, to make Linux work from a thumbdrive, here you can set the persistent file size which acts as a free space where all your data can be saved.

Answer (score -1):

You can still try [NDisWrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper), if your wifi does not work. It is wrapper around windows wifi drivers.